# Is this set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ closed?

Tags: general-topology

Is $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x=\frac1n\}$ $, n \in \mathbb{N}, 0\leq y\leq 1$ a closed set?  I think it is but I don't have any demonstration yet.

Comment: Is $(0,0)\in A$?

Comment: No, $N$ is the usual Natural numbers without $0$

Comment: @AlonsoTorresSalas I believe Angina's question is rhetorical. Hint: Use the fact that $(0,0) \notin A$ to show that it's not closed.

Comment: A is closed if every sequence in A converges to a point in A.  Is there a sequence in A that converges to $(0,0)$?  Is $(0,0)\in A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the hints given in the comments: notice that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n \doteq \left(\frac{1}{n}, 0 \right) \in A$. And clearly $a_n \to (0, 0)$. However, $(0, 0) \notin A$, since there is no $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that satisfies $0 = \frac{1}{n}$. Therefore $\overline{A} \neq A$ and $A$ is not closed.